# 2 month old doesn't cry in the middle of the night for food, only smacks her lips or sucks on her hand

Tags: newborn, breastfeeding, feeding, bottle-feeding, night-time

My 2 month old doesn't often cry when she is hungry, especially in the middle of the night. In the night, more often I awake, and hear her smacking her lips or trying to feed on her hand. Sometimes after I use the restroom, or the heat the bottle, she has fallen back asleep. Under normal circumstances, should I feed her in the middle of the night when I hear this, or do I wait until she cries to try and encourage sleeping through the night?

She is mostly breast fed, but given a breast milk in a bottle about once a day.

She has had no problem gaining weight.

I am also concerned about moving her to her own room. If we do, we may not hear her like this in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your daughter is gaining weight well, I would just let her self soothe back to sleep and consider it a blessing that she is able to do so. I would not wake her up to feed. I think that if she was really hungry, she would eventually cry.

My own daughter (second child) was also breastfed and began sleeping through the night at 2 months old. She also sucks on her fingers and go back to sleep when she wakes in the night. She did dropped on her growth curve around that age (from the 50th percentile to the 35th) but since then she stayed there and was just fine. The doctor said that it was not a worry at all! Honestly I'm beyond thrilled that she is sleeping through the night (she is now almost 7 months), because my boy took 10 months to get there.

So if you're baby is overall in good health, just let her do her thing and enjoy your sleep.